# The calling thread cannot access this object - Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

I am setting up a `Timer` within a method with an interval of `1000` so that every second it will type another corresponding character into a `Textbox` (pretty much automating typing). When I check for `_currentTextLength == _text.Length` I get the threading error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

```
 public void WriteText(string Text)
    {
        timer = new Timer();

        try
        {
            _text = Text;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed_WriteText);
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("WriteText timer could not be started.");
        }
    }
    // Write Text Timer Event
    void timer_Elapsed_WriteText(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxAutomationPeer peer = new TextBoxAutomationPeer(_textBox);
        IValueProvider valueProvider = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Value) as IValueProvider;

        valueProvider.SetValue(_text.Substring(0, _currentTextLength));
        if (_currentTextLength == _text.Length) // Error here
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer = null;
            return;
        }

        _currentTextLength++;
    }
```

The variable `_text` is a private class variable and so is `_currentTextLength`. `_textBox` is self explanatory.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: you need to use dispatcher.Invoke before call the _text.Length, as it inovked from another thread "not the thread it created on"...

Comment: @Moo-Juice: That's win-forms, but in principle it's the same...

Comment: @H.B., good point - thanks.

Comment: So when you googled for the error message what did you find and what wasn't clear about the information you discovered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) instead of a Timer.

> A timer that is integrated into the Dispatcher queue which is
>   processed at a specified interval of time and at a specified priority.

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

this simply means that you are trying to access some UI element from a thread other then it was created on. To overcome this you need to access it like this

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        //access it here
    }));
```

Note: If you want to check whether you can access it normally or not you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx)

```
Dispatcher.CheckAccess
```