# Error - An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred... The calling thread cannot access this object

Tags: c#

I have the following code where I have a single `TextBox` which the user uses for entering a file name. What I want to happen is that when the user types the file name the search won't happen until he/she stops/pauses typing, similar to the way searches work in windows explorer, Outlook etc.

With the code below I'm getting the following error...

**InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code**

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object
>   because a different thread owns it.

Error points to line `var fName = inputFileName.Text;` in the `findFile()` method.

Any idea what could be wrong?

### CODE:

```
namespace FileFinder
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEvent);
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Stop();
        }
        private void inputFileName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Start();
        }

        public void TimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            findFile();
        }

        private void findFile()
        {
            var fType = ".pdf";
            var fName = inputFileName.Text; // error points to this line
            var fileName = fName.Trim() + fType;

            var file = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SomeFolder\", fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
            if (file == null) {
                myButton.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else {
                myButton.Background = Brushes.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17955298/284240

Comment: Enclosing `var fName = inputFileName.Text;`  inside `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                });` did the trick. Excuse my ignorance but what would be considered the Main Thread, based on my code?